# Django & Stripe: How to send error messages?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I integrated Stripe in my project and as long all credit card details are fine, my app works perfectly. However, I didn't integrate yet error message handling and I have a bit a problem to understand how this works. I am not that familiar with Ajax yet, and maybe there lies the problem. Looking into the [reference API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#error_handling), and clicking on Python, this doesn't look like Python code to me, and I don't know how to handle the error message handling as it's explained there.

Can anyone help me out with the attached code? I also would be interested what I have to look into and learn, to better understand what's written under Python in the API reference.

```
def stripe_charge(self, transaction_profile, **kwargs):
        try:
            c = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=kwargs['total']*100,
                currency='eur',
                description=kwargs['order_id'],
                receipt_email=transaction_profile.email,
                source=kwargs['token'],
            )

            new_charge_obj = self.model(
                    transaction_profile = transaction_profile,
                    stripe_id = c.id,
                    paid = c.paid,
                    refunded = c.refunded,
                    outcome = c.outcome,
                    outcome_type = c.outcome['type'],
                    seller_message = c.outcome.get('seller_message'),
                    risk_level = c.outcome.get('risk_level'),
            )
            new_charge_obj.save()

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
          # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
          body = e.json_body
          err  = body.get('error', {})

          # print "Status is: %s" % e.http_status
          # print "Type is: %s" % err.get('type')
          # print "Code is: %s" % err.get('code')
          # # param is '' in this case
          # print "Param is: %s" % err.get('param')
          # print "Message is: %s" % err.get('message')

          return False, e

        return new_charge_obj.paid, new_charge_obj.seller_message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the messages module included in django.

```
import django.contrib.messages
# usage
messages.error(request, "Something bad happened")
```

Documentation : [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: @JonProgrammer I'm glad.